# passing functions as arguments in emacs lisp

Tags: elisp

I am unsure how exactly emacs lisp treats function objects, is there a hidden argument that I am not seeing, when I have this then when I hit `C-c p` it gives the error 
`Wrong type argument: commandp, load-cenet-files`

I don't know lisp at all.

```
(defun load-cenet-files ()
  (load-file "~/.emacs.d/cedet/common/cedet.elc")
  (require 'semantic-gcc)
)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c p") '(load-cenet-files))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emacs distinguishes between *functions* and *commands* - the latter are a special type of functions, namely those that can be invoked interactively by the user. The error message `Wrong type argument: commandp, load-cenet-files` tells you that some point in the code is expecting a command, but got something else. `commandp` is a predicate function that checks if its argument is a command; here, it tested `load-cenet-files` and found that is is not a command, thus barfed.

You can turn a function into a command by declaring it interactive. You do this by adding the `(interactive)` declaration as the first line after the `(defun function-name (args)`. Note that `(interactive)` is a special construction, it is not really a function call, but rather a declaration.

```
(defun load-cenet-files ()
  (interactive)
  (load-file "~/.emacs.d/cedet/common/cedet.elc")
  (require 'semantic-gcc)
)
```

Once you turned a function into a command, you can then call it via `M-x function-name`. Also, if you want to bind a function to a keyboard shortcut, it must be a command. The latter is exactly why you're seeing that error message: you've bound the `load-cenet-files` function to <kbd>C-c p</kbd> but it is a function, not a command. Once you insert `(interactive)` you should be fine.

Lastly, it seems somewhat unusual that you're trying to bind this functionality to a keyboard shortcut. Could you not just put the `load-file` and `require` into your ".emacs" file? Or, if you don't want the files to be loaded globally, attach it to a [mode-specific hook](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html)?

Comment: Thanks alot, I would definitely upvote you for this well thought out and informative answer if I had the rep. The reason that I want to bind this to a keyboard shortcut is cedet takes a long time to load, and one of the things I love about emacs is the ability to open it up in no time to view and edit a file, unlike big graphical ide's. I could add a hook, I was using this, but I don't want to load it when I am only trying to view a file. I want to reserve it for when I am going to do serious coding.

Answer (score 3):

It wants an interactive function http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/Interactive.html#Interactive which would potentially allow the user to enter parameters to your function. If you don't want any, something like this might work:

```
(defun load-cenet-files ()
  (interactive)
  (load-file "~/.emacs.d/cedet/common/cedet.elc")
  (require 'semantic-gcc)
)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c p") 'load-cenet-files)
```